# SoapUI correlation (property transfer)

Tags: properties, soapui, correlation

I have a REST request that respond with the following:

```
{
   "access_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6IlQwWE8xNnAtMmZzMWxremV5",
   "expires_in": 2592000,
   "token_type": "Bearer"
}
```

I want to take the value of `access_token`, store it in a property and reuse it for two subsequent requests.

Following some tutorial [here](http://www.soapui.org/functional-testing/properties/transferring-properties.html), when running the request that obtains the `access_token` I get a:

> error parsing target property: error unexpected element CDATA

But why?

There is no CDATA in my raw response.

Comment: "Following some tutorial" is not good enough! What *exactly* did you do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've problems using `transfer properties step` to get the JSON value from your response, you can use a `groovy test step` to achieve your goal.

So create a `groovy test step` to parse your response, get your value and set it as a property (for example at `testCase` level) with the follow code:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

// get response using the name of your test step
def response = context.expand('${REST Test Request#Response}')
// parse response
def jsonResp = new JsonSlurper().parseText(response)
// get the token an set as a property in the testCase
testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue('access_token',jsonResp.access_token)
```

Then in the other `testSteps` (REST or SOAP...) you can use the follow code to get the `access_token` value you set in the `testCase`:

```
${#TestCase#access_token}
```

Hope this helps,